# Giving each string in a list a score based off number of special keywords present

Tags: elixir

I've spent two days searching documentation and can't figure out what to do. I want to eventually have a list of reviews evaluated to see if each contains any of the special keywords in a separate list. Each time one of the keywords is present I want to add 1 to a score for each review. The goal is to find the review that's the most overly positive based on how many times overly positive words (like "amazing") are used.

I have tried this function with every Enum or List method I can find to run the evaluation that tells if a keyword is contained in the review but can't get it to return anything

```
def special_words() do
      spec = get_body()
      for {title, x} <- spec do
        %{title: title,
          special_words_present: x |> Enum.any?(["Extremely", "Definitely","Amazing","Very","Best","Great","Excellent","Awesome","Incredibly","Beyond","Loved","Really","Highly"], fn y -> y in spec end)
     }
      end
end
```

I've tried to really really dumb it down to this:

```
def special_words() do
      spec = get_body()
      for {title, x} <- spec do
        %{title: title,
          special_words_present: if "Excellent" || "Awesome" in x do
            x
          else
            "Not Present"
          end
        }
      end 
 end
```

but no luck with that either. Any ideas on what I need to be focusing on to solve this? Also if anyone has any ideas on the scoring portion of the function that would be appreciated too. Thanks.

Comment: Your last few questions all ask for something very specific in the title, but when we look at the details, they are basically "help me implement the next part of my screen scraping application". I think your time might be spent more productively spending a month or two to learn some Elixir fundamentals, rather than getting stuck for days on each step of your implementation.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip. Absolutely correct. I’m taking a couple of elixir courses on Udemy and it all seemed pretty straightforward so I ventured into the unknown which as you know by now is not going great. Any suggestions on a good middle ground learning resource in between the often generic learning in a structured course and the wild Wild West of creating something from scratch with no roadmap? Thank you immensely for your patience and your help so far by the way. My understanding of elixir has grown immensely though this process regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is count the number of desired strings are in a list of strings.

You could do that by using [`Enum.count/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#count/2). This function accepts another function as its second argument which is what to count. In your case, it would be count each word that is in the list of desired words.

```elixir
desired_words = ["Extremely", "Definitely", ...]

sentences = [
  ~w"Here's a sentence that doesn't contain any counted words",
  ~w"This sentence Definitely contains once counted word",
  ~w"This Amazing and Excellent sentence is Beyond 2 points"
]

for sentence <- sentences do
  {Enum.count(sentence, &(&1 in desired_words)), sentence}
end
```

This gives you a list of `{count, sentence}` tuples:

```elixir
[
  {0,
   ["Here's", "a", "sentence", "that", "doesn't", "contain", "any", "counted",
    "words"]},
  {1, ["This", "sentence", "Definitely", "contains", "one", "counted", "word"]},
  {3,
   ["This", "Amazing", "and", "Excellent", "sentence", "is", "Beyond", "2",
    "points"]}
]
```

---

You could improve the efficiency slightly by using [`MapSet`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html) instead of a list for the desired words. This is because checking if an item is in a `MapSet` is an O(1) operation, but checking if it's in a list is O(n), because it has to traverse the list each time to find the element:

```elixir
desired_words = MapSet.new(["Extremely", "Definitely", "Amazing", ...])

sentences = [...]

for sentence <- sentences do
  {Enum.count(sentence, &MapSet.member?(desired_words, &1)), sentence}
end
```